# print comma separated value from database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table column which is separate with comma. Column name is **'Intro'** and the values are:

> Rumi, school,2018,lecturer

I need to show this comma separated value one by one. The output should be like this :

> Rumi

I tried this code in my blade file :

```
@foreach ($evaluation as $client)
  @foreach (explode(',', $client->Intro) as $client_intro)
      {{ $client_intro[0]}}
          @endforeach
           @endforeach
```

but this shows nothing. what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try This:**

```
@foreach ($evaluation as $client)
  @foreach (explode(',', $client->Intro) as $client_intro)
      {{ $client_intro }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

Just simply remove the index

```
{{ $client_intro[0]}}  ---->>  should be --> {{ $client_intro}}
```